# How to compare the value of two elements between two windows in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, jasmine, protractor

I need save the value of  "$$('[title="Ir al documento"]').first().getText();"  for comparing in another Window.

```
  it('spec', function () {

  var text;

  $$('#links-list a').first().click().then(function () {
            browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function () {

                    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#introBienvenida .boton')), 5000);
                    $('#introBienvenida .boton').click();

                    element(by.id("texto")).sendKeys('texto refundido');
                    element(by.id("buttonSearch")).click();

                    text = $$('[title="Ir al documento"]').first().getText(); // I need save to compare this value.
                    $$('[title="Ir al documento"]').first().click();

                });
                browser.driver.close();
                browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]); // Back again.
            });
        });

        expect($('#adDoc0 .AD-objetivo').getText()).toEqual(text); // I need assert the content of text

});
```

EDITED:

What I need is to compare the value of Element in window with handle 1 and the value of Element in window with handle 0.

First I have to click in element of window with handle 0, then I clicking on document in the window with handle 1 and I get a value, after I have to back to window with handle 0 to get a value and compare with the value of the window with handle 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor is developed on the principles of promises and callbacks. `getText()` function returns a promise with the text value. There are many ways to handle this situation,

1. Expect it inside the promise of the `getText()` function. (this one's already posted as answer by @user2020347).
2. Save it using a global variable and then use it outside the function you need -

   ```
   var text;
   $$('#links-list a').first().click().then(function () {
       //switch to window 1
       $$('[title="Ir al documento"]').first().getText().then(function(windowOneText){
           text = windowOneText;
       });
       //close the windows to go back to first window
   });
   expect($('#adDoc0 .AD-objetivo').getText()).toEqual(text);
   ```
3. Pass it on to the next callback function as an argument -

   ```
   var text;
   $$('#links-list a').first().click().then(function () {
       //switch to window 1
       $$('[title="Ir al documento"]').first().getText().then(function(windowOneText){
           text = windowOneText;
       });
       //close the windows to go back to first window
       return text;
   }).then(function(argText){
       expect($('#adDoc0 .AD-objetivo').getText()).toEqual(argText);
   });
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Solved with choice 2. I forgot that getText() returns promises. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass it through with a promise.

```
$$('[title="Ir al documento"]').first().getText().then(function(documentTitleText){
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
    expect($('#adDoc0 .AD-objetivo').getText()).toEqual(documentTitleText);
});
```

Comment: What I need is to compare the value of Element in window with handle 1 and the value of Element in window with handle 0.